# Previous Values and subtract to Current Value thru DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Newbie Here, I have a question can you help me on how to minus the previous value to current value.

Here's my sample data

| Year | Month | ColumnNames_Arr[1] | Dax_Index | Prev Row | ABS Pearl - PP Variance | Prev Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | January | 4 | 1 | 1 | 47,995,316,145.30 | 41,311,832,137,577.00 |
| 2022 | January | 5 | 2 | 1 | 45,209,572,763.95 | 41,322,103,602,554.00 |
| 2022 | January | 6 | 3 | 2 | 47,356,507,708.56 | 41,347,782,264,996.50 |
| 2022 | January | 7 | 4 | 3 | 44,216,874,999.36 | 41,347,782,268,939.00 |
| 2022 | January | 8 | 5 | 4 | 43,355,752,518.63 | 41,352,918,001,428.00 |
| 2022 | January | 9 | 6 | 5 | 30,737,632,408.37 | 41,352,917,997,485.00 |
| 2022 | January | 10 | 7 | 6 | 12,426,555,561.18 | 41,440,202,704,645.70 |
| 2022 | January | 11 | 8 | 7 | 8,455,805,007.64 | 13,653,252,477,600.00 |
| 2022 | January | 12 | 9 | 8 | 4,270,561,948.35 | 13,653,252,477,600.00 |
| 2022 | January | 13 | 10 | 9 | 3,255,537,329.87 | 6,466,767,735,895.66 |
| 2022 | January | 14 | 11 | 10 | 1,413,187,797.47 | 4,251,783,486,823.47 |
| 2022 | January | 15 | 12 | 11 | 1,590,936,958.80 | 792,524,041,378.52 |
| 2022 | January | 20 | 13 | 12 | 1,166,652,069.73 | 792,622,029,019.64 |
| 2022 | January | 21 | 14 | 13 | 1,074,232,861.42 | 2,016,297,717,439.00 |
| 2022 | January | 22 | 15 | 14 | 417,314,123.54 | 2,016,297,717,439.00 |
| 2022 | January | 24 | 16 | 15 | 334,977,061.27 | 605,143,918,528.92 |
| 2022 | January | 25 | 17 | 16 | 337,486,960.07 | 258,818,798,710.00 |
| 2022 | January | 26 | 18 | 17 | 312,943,283.87 | 258,818,798,710.00 |
| 2022 | January | 28 | 19 | 18 | 309,823,301.63 | 258,818,798,710.00 |
| 2022 | January | 29 | 20 | 19 | 267,521,363.21 | 258,818,798,710.00 |
| 2022 | January | 34 | 21 | 20 | 265,011,464.41 | 45,829,617,248.84 |
| 2022 | January | 35 | 22 | 21 | 265,011,464.41 | 45,829,617,248.84 |
| 2022 | February | 4 | 1 | 1 | 61,329,820,813.11 | 51,799,995,259,173.30 |
| 2022 | February | 5 | 2 | 1 | 58,239,996,756.14 | 51,799,995,259,174.00 |
| 2022 | February | 6 | 3 | 2 | 71,458,764,215.45 | 51,812,661,843,819.00 |

Comment: I can only see Prev Value in your table, no Current Value? You should also include a few expected results and clarify whether you're looking for a `Measure` or a `Calculated Column`.

Comment: Hi Apologies on that, my current value is "ABS Pearl-PP Variance". Some of the column like Dax_Index and Prev_Row created using Dax column. The Prev Value I'm trying to get the current value using this formula dax: 
Prev Value= CALCULATE(MAX('CTR Transction'[ABS Pearl - PP Variance]),
ALL('CTR Transction'),
'CTR Transction'[Date] = EARLIER('CTR Transction'[Date]),
'CTR Transction'[Dax_Index] = EARLIER('CTR Transction'[Prev Row]))

Comment: Still not sure I understand. You have posted a column called Prev Value in your table, so why can't you just subtract this from your current value?

Comment: In the column Prev Value are not correct. I need to create new Prev Value that matches the value from "ABS Pearl-PP Pearl Variance"